How to deduce the general case of Green's theorem from rectangular case?

The proof of Green's Theorem for rectangle is very simple.
The proof for triangle is not too bad, and the general case follows ( at least intuitively ) from the triangle case.
But I'm lazy.
So is there a quick way to deduce the general case, or at least the triangle case from the rectangle case ?.

An attempt to make the question more precise:

Suppose for each smooth Vector Field $\mathbf{F}$ and each piecewise smooth simple closed curve $C$ we have a number $\langle\mathbf{F},C\rangle$, and the map $(\mathbf{F},C)\mapsto\langle\mathbf{F},C\rangle$ satisfies various nice properties such as "additivity" over regions, and
$$\langle\mathbf{F},C\rangle=\iint_R \left(\frac{\partial
F_y}{\partial x}-\frac{\partial F_x}
{\partial y}\right)dxdy$$
whenever $C$ bounds a rectangle $R$, must the formula be true for arbitrary $C$ ?.


(1) Any shape can be approximated by a large number of very small rectangles.
(2) The dot product on the inner sides of the rectangles cancel each other out to reduce to the larger loop alone.

Once you have it for triangles, you can generalize to piecewise linear shapes by using vertex subdivision. Then you can use continuity to go to a more general class of curves.

@Paul I hesitate to approximate a shape by small rectangles, because it doesn't work for line integral of scalar function. That it works for line integral of vector field is truly a miracle in my opinion. Approximation by triangles does work, but that's exactly what I want to avoid here...

@newaccount point 2 does not apply to the scalar function case.

@Paul I mean look at those zig-zag curves in the link. Their lengths certainly don't converge to the circumference of the circle, but their line integrals of a vector field $\mathbf{F}$ do converge to the line integral along the circle. How to explain the difference?

I wouldn’t recommend the argument by approximation via rectangles. The best way is to use partitions of unity; this is just a slight shift in philosophy where rather than chopping up the domain, you chop up your vector field (or more generally, differential forms).
